# Dynamically sorting and filtering projected Entity SQL results

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-sql

I have the following query which I want to sort or filter using projected class names:

```
List<CompanyInfo> list = new List<CompanyInfo>();

using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    list.AddRange(
                  db.Companies.Include("Projects")
                  .Select(row => new CompanyInfo()
                  {
                      ProjectCount = (from s in row.Projects
                                      where s.Company.fId == row.fId
                                      select s.pId).Count(),
                      Id = satir.fId,
                  })
                 //.OrderBy("ProjectCount") //<== what I want to do
            );
}
```

I want to dynamically order this query using `ProjectCount` or `Id` columns same as ESQL, like `.OrderBy("ProjectCount")`. Since the query result is IQueryable instead of ObjectContext it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, I used helper extension methods:

[Sorting in IQueryable using string as column name](http://blog.cincura.net/229310-sorting-in-iqueryable-using-string-as-column-name/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like this: `.OrderBy(p => p.ProjectCount)`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Dynamic LINQ library.
Here is a [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) that seems to describe your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some nifty things with LINQ, if you know what to do. Maybe something like this??

```
        var query = db.Companies.Include("Projects").Select(row => 
            new CompanyInfo() 
            { 
                ProjectCount = (from s in row.Projects where s.Company.fId == row.fId select s.pId).Count(), 
                Id = satir.fId, 
            });

        if (orderBy) // orderBy is bool, that tels you what to order by
            query = query.OrderBy(x => x.ProjectCount);
        else
            query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Id);

        list.AddRange(query);
```